# How to solve "insufficent space on the device" error on Samsung Captivate

Tags: google-play-store, cache

I have a Samsung Captivate, running the stock Froyo ROM, rooted.  When I try to install a large app from the Market, I get the error "insufficent space on the device", for apps of ~40 MB, with 700+MB free.  I first noticed it with "Jelly Defense" on Google's Christmas-week sale, but you can see it for yourself if you try the free "Reiner Knizia's Labyrinth" which is also quite large.

This is a common problem -- just Google it and you'll see dozens of posts around the Internet going back almost a year. From those posts, I've tried two free apps that are supposed to help, "Market Fix" and "Cache Fixer", but neither has done the trick yet.  As I understand it, both are supposed to re-mount /cache as a loopback file on the SD card.  I don't know why they don't work.  If anybody has fixed this specifically on the i9000 series (SGS1, Captivate, Fascinate, etc), please let me know how!

Comment: I had this on my Vibrant and now that I think about it I think it went away after I cleared the cache.  Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always the way, innit?  5 minutes after I ask, I stumble across [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=16960244&postcount=3014).  It's not super elegant but its success is in its simplicity.  Simply replace the dedicated /cache partition with a link to the internal SD card, and Bob's your uncle.  Has to be repeated on reboot, so not perfect, but way better than not installing at all!

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting that error is because your /datadata cache is filling up. The way I solved it on my phone was to get the MarketFix app from the market, and run that. It's a small app, so you shouldn't have any trouble downloading it. This probably does the same thing you found, but you only have to run it once.